# Bash script which plots data using XMGRACE tool

Tags: bash, xmgrace

I have written a bash script that generates files containing data and saves them to a directory. I would like my script to also plot these files using xmgrace.

Initially I just need a command line or series of command lines that will create an xmgrace file, save it, choose the scales of the y and x axis, set the y axis to be logarithmic, label the x and y axis and title the graph.

I have tried the line to start with

```
    xmgrace filename xaxis label "Label 1" yaxis label "Label 2" PRINT TO "filename.eps" DEVICE "EPS" OP "level2"
```

This plots the data but does not put the labels on it or save it and the terminal returns

```
    Can't stat file xaxis
    Can't stat file label
    Can't stat file Label 1
    ...
    ...
```

Is there also a flag I can put in this command line so that xmgrace does not actually open the file, it just creates it and saves it. This would be much better when I use it in the Bash Script.

Thank you very much

p.s. I am only using xmgrace because it it the plotting tool I am most familiar with to use manually. I would welcome any suggestion of more appropriate tools for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to call xmgrace/Grace without the GUI (using `gracebat`), but the commands you have used must first be inside a script file.

Contents of file "script.bat":

```
xaxis label "Label 1" 
yaxis label "Label 2" 
DEVICE "EPS" OP "level2"
PRINT TO "plot.eps"
PRINT
```

Now, for a two-column data file "data.dat" you call a sister executable named `gracebat` which is the same as `xmgrace` but operates in batch mode (without the GUI):

`gracebat -nosafe data.dat -batch script.bat`

where

`-batch <script>` tells grace to look for and execute a script file (does *not* tell grace to run in batch mode!).

`-nosafe` overrides the default safe mode, which is supposed to stop file modifications. Without it you would see an error message (although in my case the plot file was still written).