# How to plot line in xmgrace using Bash or shell script

Tags: bash, shell, xmgrace

I want to plot a vertical dotted red line in particular point (say 2.2) in xmgrace using script

Answer (score 2):

You can either use an external tool such as [pygrace](http://pygrace.github.io/) or use grace's built-in batch capabilities. These have been touched upon here on SO before (see, for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411095/bash-script-which-plots-data-using-xmgrace-tool) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068223/how-to-use-batch-script-with-xmgrace)).

The following script plots a datafile (`exp.dat`) as empty circles, another data file (`line.dat`) as a red dotted line and sets the ranges, labels and major ticks of the two axes:

```
READ NXY "exp.dat"
READ NXY "line.dat"

WORLD XMIN 0
WORLD XMAX 5
WORLD YMIN 1
WORLD YMAX 5
xaxis label "My x label"
xaxis tick major 1
yaxis label "My y label"
yaxis tick major 1

s0 line type 0
s0 symbol 1
s0 symbol size 1.5

s1 linestyle 2
s1 color 2
```

To generate a vertical red dotted line that passes through 2.2 the contents of`line.dat` should be something like

```
2.2 0
2.2 10000
```

You can generate such a file in a bash script with the following command:

```
echo "2.2 0\n2.2 10000" > line.dat
```

Save the script as `mybatch.xmg` and call it like this:

```
xmgrace -batch mybatch.xmg
```

If you want to directly generate an output you can add this directive:

```
PRINT TO "myplot.eps"
DEVICE "EPS" OP "level2"
PRINT
```

which will save your plot as `myplot.eps` (add `-nosafe` when calling `xmgrace` to get rid of the warnings).

Comment: thank you, but I have only one file  and vertical red dotted line not plotted. The main problem is  I want plot **some** dotted line in my graph. also  want same color (black) data except dotted line.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I think that my answer solves your problem, *as it is written now*. I have added a line on how to automatically generate the `line.dat` file in a bash script if that's what you were asking.